# 01861-literal-does-not-match-format-string

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

I have a query to select last 5 vehicle are recently reported. which is stored in  "VEHICLE_IN" table.

```
SELECT R.REG_NO FROM
(SELECT G.REG_NO FROM VEHICLE_IN G 
 INNER JOIN VEHICLE_MASTER M ON G.REG_NO=M.REG_NO 
 WHERE to_date((IN_DATE||' '||IN_TIME),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') >= (SYSDATE-30/1440) 
 AND M.VEHICLE_STAND='STAND1' 
 ORDER BY G.IN_DATE DESC, G.IN_TIME DESC) R 
WHERE ROWNUM <= 5  
GROUP BY R.REG_NO ;
```

[Record format (VARCHAR2(20)):  IN_DATE : '2016-03-21'; IN_TIME: '18:27']

The query returns an error

[image]

But the condition works in some other query.

Anybody please help me to find out the mistake..

Comment: Why are you storing the date and time separately, and as strings? Look at all the records in the table, some will not contain valid date/time representations. Which would be impossible if you were using the proper data type.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply sir, But this query works for me  -    " SELECT REG_NO,IN_DATE,IN_TIME FROM VEHICLE_IN WHERE TO_DATE((IN_DATE||' '||IN_TIME ),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') >= (SYSDATE-30/1440) "

Comment: I can't think of any way for that to be possible if they are both looking at the same tables with the same data. I could believe the query in the question worked and the one in the comment got that error, but not the other way around. If IN_DATE was a date not a string session settings could have an effect, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Without being able to see the tables and data I'm not sure what is happening, sorry.